# Is there a way to display a different small image (icon) for each row of a NSTableColumn?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to display a different small image (icon) for each row of a NSTableColumn ?

I don't necessarily need to add a new column for it, I was wondering if I can just add the icon in front of the text of each row.

I know there is the method: `- (void)setDataCell:(NSCell *)aCell` . However this method seems to use the *same* cell for all rows, which is not what I want.

Is there a solution to this problem which doesn't require to subclass the NSTableColumn ? If not, what should I subclass ?

thanks

Comment: are you using view based tableview ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya No Cell-based. That's why I was only taking about cells in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the cell for the column in question an NSImageCell. You can do this in Interface Builder by dragging an "Image Cell" from the object library onto the column. Then select the column and you'll be able to bind to an image source via one of the Data, Value, Value Path, or Valueurl bindings. Which one you choose depends on whether the source property in your model returns NSData, NSImage, NSString path, or NSURL url, respectively. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSImageCell.html) on NSImageCell bindings for more complete information.

Cells are the same for each row, because they're a lightweight class used as a performance optimization for drawing. That doesn't mean that each row has to use the cell to draw the same image though, any more than the text columns' cells have to draw the same string for each row.

If you really need the image to be in the same column as text, you'll have to do something more like duDE explains. Off the top of my head, I believe bindings should be still possible in this case, but you'll have to write more code to make that work. Rather than do that, I would probably switch to using a view based NSTableView, which makes putting multiple views in a single column/row easy, and will let you continue to use bindings without any extra work.

EDIT: duDE's answer was deleted, but to summarize, it suggested creating a custom NSCell subclass that would draw both an image and text.